# External Url not working in Ionic in Image Tag

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic-view

I am using an external url for displaying an image in my mobile application which is built with `ionic framework`. When I am checking it in the browser using `ionic serve` everything is fine. But on a real device, the images are not displayed. For example:

```
 <img ng-src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Dave_Cote_Headshot.jpg/220px-Dave_Cote_Headshot.jpg" />
```

Comment: did you install whitelist plugin?

Comment: Hey @RHUL, are you performing test on iOS or Android? If iOS, which version of iOS you are actually using for test?

Comment: Might also want to check to make sure your content security police allows that site as a source: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist#content-security-policy

Answer (score 0):

Please install **[this](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova/inappbrowser/inappbrowser.html)** plugin

```
cordova plugin add https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git
```

**html**

```
<img onclick="window.open('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/82/Dave_Cote_Headshot.jpg/220px-Dave_Cote_Headshot.jpg', '_system'" />
```

**[Refer](https://blog.nraboy.com/2014/07/launch-external-urls-ionicframework/)**